# Database Error. SQL query is not being executed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I have a form that takes two values as input and parses them using post method to the next file where I have this piece of code. This should save the two values in the MySQL database. But strangely it doesn't .. and in the output error I get is this: **0: 0:**

```
$service_name = $_POST['service_name'];
$service_price = $_POST['service_price'];

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "db_user", "pa$$");

mysql_select_db("database", $link);
echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link). "\n";

mysql_select_db("database", $link);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO service_tbl(id_service, service_name, service_price) VALUES(NULL,'$service_name','$service_price')", $link);
echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "\n";
```

In my database table `service_tbl`, `id_service`is auto_increment and the other two columns are VARCHAR. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Consider using `mysqli` or `PDO` and not `mysql_*'.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO service_tbl( service_name, service_price)     VALUES('{$service_name}','{$service_price}')", $link);
```

use this as `Id_service` is auto-increement you cannot insert it.

Comment: doesn't work. Still getting **0: 0:** as output! :/

Comment: check your mysql connection is established properly. $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "db_user", "pa$$"); "pa$$" may be causing problems.

Comment: check your mysql connection is established properly. $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "db_user", "pa$$"); "pa$$" may be causing problems. Use $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "db_user", "pa$$") or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

Comment: password is not exactly 'pa$$' I just used it here for the sake of it!

Comment: @Hossain you can easily debub if there is connection problem or database selection problem. store the query in a variable and print the variable also try running the query explicitly.This should certainly help solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert `NULL` in an auto increment column, wich is not possible, simply change to

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO service_tbl( service_name, service_price)     VALUES('$service_name','$service_price')", $link);
```

Then I  would like to remember you that `mysql_` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and indeed you are at risk of `sql injection`, have a look here [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). You should use prepared statment to avoid any risk

Comment: doesn't work. Still getting **0: 0:** as output! :/

Comment: @hossainahmedsaiman try to `echo $service_name;`, what does it print?

Comment: it prints the parsed values alright!

Comment: I know the vulnerability issue. But SQL injection is not a big issue for me right now.

Comment: @Hossainahmedsaiman Did you check data is not inserted in your table?

Comment: I checked. It's not being inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Some ammendments:

1. As it was already said in the other answers/comments, don't use the deprecated `mysql_*` functions.
2. There is no need to pass a value for the auto-increment field.
3. Change your debug output into real error checking.
4. Sanitize user input.

The revised code:

```
$service_name  = $_POST['service_name'];
$service_price = $_POST['service_price'];

$mysqli = new MySQLi('localhost', 'db_user', 'pa$$', 'database');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    throw new ErrorException("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO service_tbl (service_name, service_price) VALUES ('%s', $f)",
    $mysqli->real_escape_string($service_name),
    (float)$service_name
);
// At this point, you can echo the query to test it in eg. phpMyAdmin
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if ($result === false) {
    throw new ErrorException("Query failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);

while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
    print_r($obj);
}

// Free result set
$result->close();
```